# Is there any way to rewrite this query to be more "LINQ-ier"?

Tags: c#, linq

The following parses a `/`-delimited URL path into a dictionary of key-value pairs:

```
    private Dictionary<string, string> ParsePathParameters(string path)
    {
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
        {
            return parameters;
        }

        var pathSegments = path.Split(new[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        for (var i = pathSegments.Length - 1; i >= pathSegments.Length % 2; i -= 2)
        {
            parameters.Add(pathSegments[i - 1], pathSegments[i]);
        }

        return parameters;
    }
```

The input format is `[/preamble][/key1/value1][/key2/value2]...[/keyN/valueN]` so for example, given the input "/foo/1/bar/Thing" or "/slug/foo/1/bar/Thing", the output would be:

```
Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "foo", "1" },
    { "bar", "Thing" },
}
```

This code is good code; simple, self-explanatory, and fast. But, because I like a challenge, I decided to rewrite it in LINQ:

```
    private Dictionary<string, string> ParsePathParameters(string path)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
        {
            return new Dictionary<string, string>();
        }

        var pathSegments = path.Split(new[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        var skip = pathSegments.Length % 2;

        return pathSegments.Skip(skip)
            .Where((_, i) => i % 2 == 0)
            .Select((_, i) => i * 2)
            .ToDictionary(i => pathSegments[i + skip], i => pathSegments[i + skip + 1]);
    }
```

This works, but it definitely doesn't feel optimal, probably because it also doesn't feel like the "right" way to achieve this using LINQ. Can anyone suggest if it's possible to write this code in a more "LINQ-like" manner, and if so give me some pointers in that regard?

Comment: I'm sure how useful this code is.  Normally when searching a path you need some level of hierarchical dictionary.  You could have 100 different folders named foo and bar and some may be one level deep and others 20 or 30 layers deep.  AND some could have odd number of levels and others EVEN.  Your code is assuming an even number of layers.

Comment: Looking online, it seems like this should be the best solution for "linq"ifying the dictionary...but the real question becomes *why*? Your original solution, while maybe a bit more uglier, seems to be the best solution, and will cause less index lookups, and unneeded array generations. Your original solution IMO is your best solution.

Comment: @jdweng The variable names are probably a little poor, "path" in this case is actually a URL segment - have clarified the question.

Comment: @FrankerZ Because I'm always interested in finding out alternative ways to achieve a certain outcome. Even if those alternatives aren't "better" in the strict sense, it's almost certain I'll come away more knowledgeable about LINQ, and that's really the objective here.

Answer (score 6):

I would write it like so:

```
private Dictionary<string, string> ParsePathParameters(string path)
{
    return GetSegmentPairs().ToDictionary(x => x.k, x => x.v);
    IEnumerable<(string k, string v)> GetSegmentPairs()
    {
        var segments = path?.Split(new[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                ?? new string[0];
        for (int i = 0, l = segments.Length; i < l; i += 2)
            yield return (segments[i+0], segments[i+1]);
    }
}
```

Don't underestimate the power of local functions and generators. Generators are great when you need to create sequences that are awkward to write as a straight linq query. Then these generators may be used within linq queries. For this particuar case, it might not even be necessary for a fairly trivial query, but for more complex queries, it's invaluable. But it's a pattern you should learn to utilize more often.

If using C# 8, I'd get in the habit of using span/memory and slices where appropriate.

```
private Dictionary<string, string> ParsePathParameters(string path)
{
    return GetSegments().ToDictionary(x => x.Span[0], x => x.Span[1]);
    IEnumerable<System.Memory<string>> GetSegments()
    {
        var segments = path?.Split(new[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) ?? new string[0];
        for (int i = 0, l = segments.Length; i < l; i += 2)
            yield return segments[^i..i+1];
    }
}
```

Otherwise if you're using MoreLINQ, you could use the `Pairwise()` along with `TakeEvery()` methods to effectively do the same thing as the `GetSegmentPairs()` method above.

```
private Dictionary<string, string> ParsePathParameters(string path) =>
    (path?.Split(new[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            ?? Enumerable.Empty<string>())
        .Pairwise(ValueTuple.Create)
        .TakeEvery(2) // pairwise produces overlapping pairs so take every other
        .ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => x[1]);
```